# I have 2 announcement bars in my code that are on/off selectable, how can I enable both of them and transition from one to the other?

Tags: html, css, if-statement, shopify, liquid

I have 2 announcement bars on my Shopify section that I created. I am able to select either one and they work perfectly. However, I would like to have them both enabled on the same bar transition from one to the other.

Here are both announcement bars. Do I need to add in some kind of transition code to make .show_announcement transition into .show_announcement2?

```
    {%- if section.settings.show_announcement -%}
  {%- if section.settings.home_page_only == false or template.name == 'index' -%}

    {%- if section.settings.link == blank -%}
      <div class="announcement-bar">
    {%- else -%}
      <a href="{{ section.settings.link }}" >
    {%- endif -%}

        <p class="announcement-bar__message">{{ section.settings.text | escape }}</p>

    {%- if section.settings.link == blank -%}            
      </div>
    {%- else -%}
      </a>
    {%- endif -%}

  {%- endif -%}
{%- endif -%}

{%- if section.settings.show_announcement2 -%}
  {%- if section.settings.home_page_only == false or template.name == 'index' -%}

    {%- if section.settings.link2 == blank -%}
      <div class="announcement-bar">
    {%- else -%}
      <a href="{{ section.settings.link2 }}" >
    {%- endif -%}

        <p class="announcement-bar__message2">{{ section.settings.text2 | escape }}</p>

    {%- if section.settings.link2 == blank -%}            
      </div>
    {%- else -%}
      </a>
    {%- endif -%}

  {%- endif -%}
{%- endif -%}


<style>
  .announcement-bar {
    background-color: {{ section.settings.announcement_bar_color }};
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;   
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;    
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .announcement-bar__message {
    background-color: {{ section.settings.announcement_bar_color }};
    text-align: center;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    color: {{ section.settings.announcement_bar_text_color }};
  }
  .announcement-bar2 {
    background-color: {{ section.settings.announcement_bar_color2 }};
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;   
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;    
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  } 
  .announcement-bar__message2 {
    background-color: {{ section.settings.announcement_bar_color2 }};
    text-align: center;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    color: {{ section.settings.announcement_bar_text_color2 }};
  }
  
</style>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Announcement bar",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "home_page_only",
      "label": "Home page only",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_announcement",
      "label": "Show announcement",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_announcement2",
      "label": "Show announcement 2",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "announcement_bar_color",
      "label": "Background color",
      "default": "#000000"
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "announcement_bar_text_color",
      "label": "Text color",
      "default": "#ffffff"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "text",
      "label": "Announcement text 1",
      "default": "Announce something here"
    },
    {
      "type": "url",
      "id": "link",
      "label": "Announcement link 1"
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "announcement_bar_color2",
      "label": "Background color",
      "default": "#000000"
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "announcement_bar_text_color2",
      "label": "Text color",
      "default": "#ffffff"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "text2",
      "label": "Announcement text 2",
      "default": "Announce something here"
    },
    {
      "type": "url",
      "id": "link2",
      "label": "Announcement link 2"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: 1. can you select both in schema? 2.  what kind of css position is that bar? 3. what do you mean by transition, a carousel?

Comment: Yes I can select both in schema. I am trying to get the same affect as this site (https://blenderseyewear.com) Right now I have 2 bars, and I want the First one to show on page, then the second one fade in over top of it, then fade back out showing the first bar again. On a loop.

Comment: I added the schema and css for reference. All of this is inside my Sections template I created called announcement-bar.liquid

Comment: I see, that website is using slick slide https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ combine the 2 bars you have and use slick slide for transition. done.

Comment: @CharlesC. Can you elaborate on how to combine the 2 bars and create the transition? I am not sure how to write this code. Any help you can provide would be apricated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
{%- if section.settings.show_announcement -%}
  {%- if section.settings.home_page_only == false or template.name == 'index' -%}

    <div class="my-slider">

    {%- if section.settings.link == blank -%}
      <div class="announcement-bar">
    {%- else -%}
      <div><a href="{{ section.settings.link }}" >
    {%- endif -%}

        <p class="announcement-bar__message">{{ section.settings.text | escape }}</p>

    {%- if section.settings.link == blank -%}            
      </div>
    {%- else -%}
      </a></div>
    {%- endif -%}

    {%- if section.settings.link2 == blank -%}
      <div class="announcement-bar">
    {%- else -%}
      <div><a href="{{ section.settings.link2 }}" >
    {%- endif -%}

        <p class="announcement-bar__message2">{{ section.settings.text2 | escape }}</p>

    {%- if section.settings.link2 == blank -%}            
      </div>
    {%- else -%}
      </a></div>
    {%- endif -%}


    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endif -%}


<style>
  .announcement-bar {
    background-color: {{ section.settings.announcement_bar_color }};
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;   
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;    
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .announcement-bar__message {
    background-color: {{ section.settings.announcement_bar_color }};
    text-align: center;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    color: {{ section.settings.announcement_bar_text_color }};
  }
  .announcement-bar2 {
    background-color: {{ section.settings.announcement_bar_color2 }};
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;   
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;    
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  } 
  .announcement-bar__message2 {
    background-color: {{ section.settings.announcement_bar_color2 }};
    text-align: center;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    color: {{ section.settings.announcement_bar_text_color2 }};
  }
  
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<script type="text-/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>


<script>
  $('.my-slider').slick();

</script>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Announcement bar",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "home_page_only",
      "label": "Home page only",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_announcement",
      "label": "Show announcement",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_announcement2",
      "label": "Show announcement 2",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "announcement_bar_color",
      "label": "Background color",
      "default": "#000000"
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "announcement_bar_text_color",
      "label": "Text color",
      "default": "#ffffff"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "text",
      "label": "Announcement text 1",
      "default": "Announce something here"
    },
    {
      "type": "url",
      "id": "link",
      "label": "Announcement link 1"
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "announcement_bar_color2",
      "label": "Background color",
      "default": "#000000"
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "announcement_bar_text_color2",
      "label": "Text color",
      "default": "#ffffff"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "text2",
      "label": "Announcement text 2",
      "default": "Announce something here"
    },
    {
      "type": "url",
      "id": "link2",
      "label": "Announcement link 2"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: Thank you this looks great. Is there a way to hide the Next and Previous buttons? So just the bar is visible?

Comment: ... did you look into the slick page document I sent. it is right there: arrows
: false.

Comment: Got it thanks so much!